# Difference between regex [A-z] and [a-zA-Z]

Tags: regex

I am using a regex to program an input validator for a text box where I only want alphabetical characters. I was wondering if `[A-z]` and `[a-zA-Z]` were equivalent or if there were differences performance wise.

I keep reading `[a-zA-Z]` on my searches and no mention of `[A-z]`.

I am using java's `String.matches(regex)`.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`[A-z]` will match ASCII characters in the range from `A` to `z`, while `[a-zA-Z]` will match ASCII characters in the range from `A` to `Z` **and** in the range from `a` to `z`. At first glance, this might seem equivalent -- however, if you look at [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/) of ASCII characters, you'll see that `A-z` includes several other characters. Specifically, they are `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, and `` ` `` (which you clearly don't want).

Comment: I guess I just really wasn't sure if there were characters between Z-a.

Comment: @Eric https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ascii I believe you'll find `[\\]^-\`` between `Z` and `a`

Answer (score 26):

When you take a look at the ASCII table, you will see following:

```
A = 65
Z = 90
a = 97
z = 122
```

So, `[A-z]` will match every char from 65 to 122. This includes these characters (`91 -> 96`) as well:

```
[\]^_`
```

This means `[A-Za-z]` will match only the alphabet, without the extra characters above.

Answer (score 16):

The a-z matchs 'a' to 'z'  A-Z matchs 'A' to 'Z' A-z matches all these as well as the characters between the 'Z' and 'a' which are [ ] ^ / _ `

Refer to http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). You'll see that there are some characters between `Z` and `a`, so you will match more than you intented to.

Answer (score 8):

The square brackets create a character class and the hyphen is a shorthand for adding every character between the two provided characters. i.e. `[A-F]` can be written `[ABCDEF]`.

The character class `[A-z]` will match every character between those characters, which in ASCII includes some other characters such as '[', '\' and ']'.

An alternative to specifying both cases would be to set the regular expression to be case-insensitive, by using the `/i` modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [ASCII chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (which Java characters are based on): there are quite a few punctuation characters situated between Z and a, namely these:

```
[\]^ _`
```