# RegEx to find two or more consecutive chars

Tags: regex

I need to determine if a string contains two or more consecutive alpha chars. Two or more `[a-zA-Z]` side by side.
Example:

```
"ab" -> valid
"a1" -> invalid
"a b" -> invalid
"a"-> invalid
"a ab" -> valid
"11" -> invalid
```

Answer (score 328, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

Comment: Possible `{2}` without the comma should also work, right?

Comment: Alexander, just to clear few things: {2} means that the lenght has to be 2. {2,} means that the lenght of the expression can be => 2

Comment: whats the reverse of 2 -< ?

Comment: @Jonathan I assume you mean "what should be used for a maximum of `max` consecutive tokens?". The answer would then be `{,max}` (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts))

Answer (score 16):

`[a-zA-Z]{2,}` does not work for two or more identical consecutive characters. To do that, you should capture any character and then repeat the capture like this:

```
(.)\1
```

The parenthesis captures the . which represents any character and `\1` is the result of the capture - basically looking for a consecutive repeat of that character. If you wish to be specific on what characters you wish to find are identical consecutive, just replace the "any character" with a character class...

```
([a-zA-Z])\1
```

Finds a consecutive repeating lower or upper case letter. Matches on `abbc123` and not `abc1223`. To allow for a space between them (i.e. a `ab`), then include an optional space in the regex between the captured character and the repeat...

```
([a-z]A-Z])\s?\1
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you missunderstood the question as it is about two letters. Your regex is for a different case: two similar letters!

Comment: This answers the actual question and was what I was looking for, many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Personally I've used:

```
[0-9][0-9]+.
```

But the [answer from Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7068787/117259), is way better.

Answer (score -7):

I'm pretty sure you can just use [A-z] instead of the [a-zA-Z] to get small and upper case alpha chars
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: -1: This is another wonderful example of why you should never use w3schools for reference or education. `[A-z]` matches more than letters. Specifically, it also matches square brackets, backslashes, carets, underscores and backticks.

Comment: Indeed, what @TimPietzcker says is correct; the characters he mentioned come between `Z` and `a`, so would be (erroneously) included in such a pattern. I second the recommendation: *Do not use w3schools!* It has a lot of subtly bad information like this.

Comment: Ouch first zing on Stack, it stings more than I thought.  So by includeing A-z it matches everything from [A-Z a bunch of stuff I don't want and  a-z] all the charcodes between capitals and non caps? http://www.danshort.com/ASCIImap/

Comment: so I can say something like [!-+]?  Also is there a way to access the charcode inside a regex something like [65-90] which would be the same as [A-Z]?

Comment: @Kevin `[65-90]` will match `5`-`9`(which also includes `6`)  and `0`!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z