# Why is bracket mandatory here?

Tags: regex, pcre

1 . `^([0-9A-Za-z]{5})+$`

vs

2 . `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}+$`

My intention is to match any string of length `n` such that `n` is a multiple of `5`.
Check here : https://regex101.com/r/sS6rW8/1.

Please elaborate why case 1 matches the string whereas case 2 doesnot.

Comment: Sorry, that was me. Wrong arrow.

Comment: Please tag your regex flavor.

Comment: @MAKZ: Was the `A-z` range in your first regex a typo?  Because `[A-z]` it's **not** the same as `[A-Za-z]`.  You can find the full explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4923380/20938).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `{n}+` doesn't mean what you think it does. In PCRE syntax, this turns `{n}` into a [*possessive quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). In other words, `a{5}+` is the same as `(?>a{5})`. It's like the second `+` in the expression `a++`, which is the same as using an [*atomic group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>a+)`.

This has no use with a fixed-length `{n}` but is more meaningful when used with `{min,max}`. So, `a{2,5}+` is equivalent to `(?>a{2,5})`.

As a simple example, consider these patterns:

```
^(a{1,2})(ab)    will match  aab -> $1 is "a", $2 is "ab"
^(a{1,2}+)(ab)   won't match aab -> $1 consumes "aa" possessively and $2 can't match
```

Answer (score 4):

In `^([0-9A-Za-z]{5})+$` you're saying any number or letter 5 characters long 1 or more times.  The `+` is on the entire group (whatever's inside the parentheses) and the `{5}` is on the `[0-9A-Za-z]`

Your second example has a no backtrack clause `{5}+`, which is different than `(stuff{5})+`

Comment: you mean one or more times ?