# Converting PCRE to POSIX regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex, pcre, posix-ere

**I am working on a MySQL database and noticed that it doesn't natively support PCRE (requires a plugin).**

I wish to use these three for some data validation (these are actually the values given to the `pattern` attribute):

1. `^[A-z\. ]{3,36}`
2. `^[a-z\d\.]{3,24}$`
3. `^(?=^.{4,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$`

**How do I do this?**
I looked on the web but couldn't find any concrete examples or answers. Also there seem to exist no utilities that could do this automatically.

I am aware that some times, such conversions are not exact and can produce differences but I am willing to try.

Comment: **Warning: Do not use the range `[A-z]` in regexes.** See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4923380/20938) for the explanation.

Comment: yeah I noticed that during testing so I changed to [A-Za-z]. Thank you for pointing out @AlanMoore :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) state that:

> MySQL uses Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions, which is aimed at conformance with POSIX 1003.2. MySQL uses the **extended version** to support pattern-matching operations performed with the `REGEXP` operator in SQL statements.

Ok, so we're talking about POSIX ERE.

[This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) lists the details between various regex flavors, so I'll use it as a cheatsheet.

---

1. `^[A-z\. ]{3,36}`

   You're using:

   - Anchors: `^`
   - Character classes: `[`...`]`
   - The range quantifier: `{n,m}`

   All of these are supported out of the box in POSIX ERE, so you can use this expression as-is. **But** escaping the `.` in the character class is redundant, and `A-z` is most probably wrong in a character class (it includes `` [\]^_\` ``), so just write:

   ```
   ^[A-Za-z. ]{3,36}
   ```
2. `^[a-z\d\.]{3,24}$`

   This one uses `\d` as well, which is unsupported in POSIX ERE. So you have to write:

   ```
   ^[a-z0-9.]{3,24}$
   ```
3. `^(?=^.{4,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$`

   Meh. You're using lookaheads. These are totally out of the scope for POSIX ERE, but you can work around this limitation by combining several SQL clauses for an equivalent logic:

   ```
   WHERE LENGTH(foo) >= 4
     AND foo REGEXP '[0-9]'
     AND foo REGEXP '[a-z]'
     AND foo REGEXP '[A-Z]'
     AND NOT foo REGEXP '[ \t\r\n]'
   ```

Comment: for the last you can do that too: `WHERE LENGTH(foo)>3 AND foo REGEXP '^[^0-9 \t\r\n]*[0-9][ \t\r\n]*$' AND foo REGEXP '[A-Z][^a-z]*[a-z]|[a-z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]'`