# MySql Regex Expression test

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to check for the digits that are separated by a . or : or /

I tried this :

```
select 'test text 30.3 " REGEXP '\d+[:./]\d+'
```

but that returned a `0`

I tried it in regex test online and it seems to be working fine and matches the '30.3'. Not sure why it's not working in mysql

Comment: Use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950724/converting-pcre-to-posix-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `\d` [in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), use ranges or `:digit:` :

```
SELECT 'test text 30.3' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]+[:./][[:digit:]]+'
```

Comment: `[:./]` should be folowed by `{1}` I think, e.g. `SELECT 'test text 30.3' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]+[:./]{1}[[:digit:]]+' `, because it should mark if seperated by `.`, `:`, `/` and not by e.g. `.:`