# Remove all [A-z] from string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove all of the `A-z` from this string:

```
aosif$!oias832unaca818
```

So far, I have

```
[^A-z]+
```

However, I need this to not stop once it finds the first match. I thought that's what greedy did :)

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, what exactly do you want to remove, *only non-English letters*?

Comment: what language are you using? in javascript for example you must add a `g` modifier to match all occurences

Comment: What language do you use/prefer?

Comment: `[^A-z]+` just matches for a character and does not remove it at all.

Comment: I'd be after getting back `$!832818`. I am just using a basic text editor, namely np++. English, exactly :)

Comment: `-` define a range in a character class, take a look at the ascii table to know exactly what contains the `A-z` range.

Comment: @JamieHutber what programming language do you want to use?

Comment: @Thealon: The regex flavor is close to PCRE, but it does not matter here since the regex required is really simple and could work in most if not all regex flavors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mind that `[A-z]` range also includes some non-letters (see [[A-z] and [a-zA-Z] difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z)).

Use

```
[A-Za-z]
```

Replace with empty string.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV2oL9/3) - result - `$!832818`

In Notepad++, you may turn off case matching (*Match case* must be OFF) and then use a simpler `[a-z]` regex:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try doing this in your editor:

replace all `[a-zA-Z]` by empty.

you may need switch the `regex` option on, depends on your editor.

test with sed :

```
kent$  echo 'aosif$!oias832unaca818'|sed 's/[a-zA-Z]//g'
$!832818
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention in the comments your using np++

in the search just put `[a-z]` replace leave as an empty sting, Check the regex box and uncheck the "match case" box. replace all and you have the required result