# Why "[" gets matched by [a-zA-Z]

Tags: c#, regex, character-class

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"test[a-zA-z]");
string st = @"this is a test1 and testA and test[abc] another testB and test(xyz) again.";
foreach(Match match in oRegex.Matches(st))
{
     Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

**Output**:

testA

test[

testB

**Question**: Why `test[` in the output? The character class [a-zA-Z] is supposed to match only alpha characters a through z and A through Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your regex. `[a-zA-z]` should be `[a-zA-Z]`.

The character `[` is between the `A` and `z` characters.

Comment: Thank you ALL for pointing out the typo. In a way the typo helped me understand the range A-z. This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4923475/1232087) helped me explain further why "[" is included in the range A-z.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm the first to post this answer how come your post displayed at first when clicking the oldest tab?

Comment: @AvinashRaj not sure. Mine is accepted now, so it will always display first. You can hover over the "2 hours ago" to see the timestamp - looks like you beat me by 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 3):

Because `[` falls within the [ascii range](http://www.asciitable.com/) `A-z`, so change `A-z` present inside the char class to `A-Z`

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"test[a-zA-Z]");
```

Answer (score 3):

Z is typo in your case .Change this `[a-zA-Z]`

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"test[a-zA-Z]");
```