# Regex to include and exclude by multi characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string where i want to remove anything with negative values for example,

```
var mystring = "+colour:black +year:2015 -model:golf";
```

I tried using following regex but it doesn't work.

```
var reg = "[+A-z:0-9]";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(mystring, @"\s*[-][^\s]*\s*", string.Empty);
```

For only positive values:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(mystring, @"\s*[+][^\s]*\s*", string.Empty);
```

For both positive and negative:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(mystring, @"\s*[+-][^\s]*\s*", string.Empty);
```

This way, you will also handle any stray hyphens with no characters but whitespace after them, and with `\s*` you will trim the output string from remanining spaces.

**Notes on the regex**: `[-+]` matches either `-` or `+` once, `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace, and `[^\s]*` matches 0 or more characters other than whitespace.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%5B-%5D%5B%5E%5Cs%5D*%5Cs*&i=%2Bcolour%3Ablack%20%2Byear%3A2015%20-model%3Agolf&r=)

[image]

Comment: Note that `[A-z]` matches not only letters but some non-letters, too. See [A-z and a-zA-Z difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).

Answer (score 1):

```
-\S+
```

Would do the same for you.

or

```
-[a-zA-Z0-9:]+
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, how can i take only the positive ?

Comment: @CodeBox for only `positive` use ` `[+][a-zA-Z0-9:]+`