# Password Validation with password bar & regExp special characters in angular using directive

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

**This app is working for me BUT if someone find any error/mistake then please correct it.**

I was create a small app for password validation using angular js directive. Where user can validate password that's required One Special & Capital character, and one num value with minimum length 8. i also created password strength bar with it.

Thanks

Here [Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/V2H1HbEwvgEWqascTRmy?p=preview) my

Here is My HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
   <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="passwordModule.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="passwordModule" ng-controller="pwdCtrl" class="container">
    <h2>Password Validation:</h2>
    <form name="form">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" 
             pattern-validator="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,8})" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <span class="alert alert-error" ng-show="form.password.$error.passwordPattern">
         Password required 1 special & capital letter, 1 numeric letter <br> &nbsp; &nbsp; Required minimum 8 letter.</span> 

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password Strength</label>
        <password-strength ng-model="user.password"></password-strength>

        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type = "text" name = "Confpassword" ng-model="user.cnfPwd" data-equal-to="password" >
        <div data-ng-show = "showmsg"> Password matched </div>
        <div data-ng-show = "hidemsg"> Password not matched </div>
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-disabled = "disabledButton"> save </button> 
 </form>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is My Controller File :

```
var pwdModule = angular.module('passwordModule', []);
//Controller
pwdModule.controller('pwdCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
  // Initialise the password as hello
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.showmsg = false;
  $scope.disabledButton = true;


  if($scope.user.password === undefined) {
    $scope.showmsg = false;
  } 

  $scope.$watch('user.cnfPwd', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if(newVal !== undefined){
      $scope.hidemsg = true;
    }

    if(newVal === $scope.user.password && $scope.user.password !== undefined) {
      $scope.showmsg = true;
      $scope.disabledButton = false;
      $scope.hidemsg = false;
    } else {
      $scope.showmsg = false;
      $scope.disabledButton = true;
    }
  })
}
]);

 // Directive: Validate a regex pattern   
 pwdModule.directive('patternValidator', [
 function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {

        var patt = new RegExp(attrs.patternValidator);

        var isValid = patt.test(viewValue);

        ctrl.$setValidity('passwordPattern', isValid);

        return viewValue;
      });
    }
  };
  }
 ]);

// Dircetive: Display strength bar
pwdModule.directive('passwordStrength', [
function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      password: '=ngModel'
    },

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

      scope.$watch('password', function(newVal) {

        var strength = isSatisfied(newVal && newVal.length >= 8) +
                        isSatisfied(newVal && /[A-z]/.test(newVal)) +
                        isSatisfied(newVal && /(?=.*\W)/.test(newVal)) +
                        isSatisfied(newVal && /\d/.test(newVal));

        var style = '',
            percent= 0;

        switch (strength) {
          case 1: 
              style = 'danger';
              percent = 25;
            break;
          case 2: 
            style = 'warning';
            percent = 50;
          break;
          case 3: 
            style = 'warning';
            percent = 75;
          break;
          case 4: 
            style = 'success';
            percent = 100;
          break;
        }

        scope.style = style;
        scope.percent = percent;

        function isSatisfied(criteria) {
          return criteria ? 1 : 0;
        }
      }, true);
    },
    template: '<div class="progress">' +
      '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-{{style}}" style="width: {{percent}}%"></div>' +
      '</div>'
  }
}
])
```

Please check this and if any modification needed then and on it. **Thanks**

Comment: Please make sure you do not have `[A-z]` but `[A-Za-z]`, and I guess you need `^(?=.*\W)` instead of `(?=.*\W)`. If *pattern-validator* expression is anchored by default, it is ok, but I'd still use `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8}`.

Comment: I posted my observations with some reference and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about errors:

> isSatisfied(newVal && /[A-z]/.test(newVal)) +

Here, `[A-z]` matches more than English letters, it also matches `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, and `` ` ``, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).

In

> isSatisfied(newVal && /(?=.*\W)/.test(newVal)) +

you should anchor the look-ahead to increase performance:

```
isSatisfied(newVal && /^(?=.*\W)/.test(newVal)) +
                       ^
```

Note that `{8,8}` is equivalent to `{8}` - exactly 8 occurrences of the preceding subpattern. Use

```
pattern-validator="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8}"
```

Or (if it is not anchored by default, can't find it anywhere):

```
pattern-validator="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8}$"
```