# Reg-Ex for password validation fails

Tags: regex

Hi my password should contain,

```
1. minimum 8 characters
2. minimum 1 special character
3. minimum 1 number
```

I am using the following reg-ex,

```
/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*d)(?=.*[A-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ]).*$/
```

But this doesn't accept the string `AAAA2@AAAA` which is 8 character long, has one speical character **@** and has one number **2**. I have very less knowledge on RegEx. Could you please tell me what is wrong with this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the string is not accepted is because you forgot the slash with `d`, and the regex requires the letter `d` to be inside the string. Fix is

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ]).*$
 ^             ^^
```

Use it with a `i` modifier. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU2dJ2/1)

`[A-z]` issue is a [well-known one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).  Also, the initial `.*` should be removed, or some parts of the regex won't validate correctly.

And speaking about optimizations: length checking can almost always be moved to the end:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ]).{8,}$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU2dJ2/2) (again, note `i` modifier).

Also, see [*Fine-Tuning: Removing One Condition*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#n-1conds):

> If you must check for `n` conditions, your pattern only needs to include `n-1` lookaheads at the most. Often, you are even able to combine several conditions into a single lookahead.

And as far as your conditions are as above (*1) minimum 8 characters, 2) minimum 1 special character, 3) minimum 1 number*) - *there is no English letter requirement* - you can even use

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ]).{8,}$
```

Comment: Hmm this will match `AAAA2@[]AA` as well, not clear from question whether this is fine or not since `[` and `]` are not in the provided character class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ])[!@#$%^&*? a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$
```

`[A-z]` is not correct and will match may more characters within ASCII 65-122 range like `[`, `]`, ` etc.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP0bD3/5)

Comment: 1.this expression fails for `aaaaaaaaaa1!` , `ABCabc1!` or any string without character `d`. 2. the user can enter only small letters without capital letters in my requirement but this expression mandates the string to have both one small and capital letters

Comment: It was actually a copy/paste error from question. `d` should have been `\d` for digit. See updated one now.