# Regex not fully matching the string

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have used http://www.regexe.com/ to test a regex I've create in order to extract the date and time from `syslog`and it's showing me that the regex is in fact correct, highlighting the date and time. However when I try this in Perl I'm returned with just the time, not the date.

so for example from the string `Dec  9 12:45:36 osboxes NetworkManager[739]: <info>   address 192.168.10.129`
I would be returned `12:45:36`

Here's my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $keywords = 'keywords.txt';
open(my $kw, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $keywords)
or die "Could not open file '$keywords' $!";    # Open the file, throw an exception if the file cannot be opened. 
chomp (my @keywordsarray = <$kw>); # Remove whitespace, and read it into an array 
close($kw);# Close the file 

my $syslog = 'syslog';
open(my $sl, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $syslog)
or die "Could not open file '$keywords' $!";    # Open the file, throw an exception if the file cannot be opened. 
chomp (my @syslogarray = <$sl>); # Remove whitespace, and read it into an array 
close($sl);# Close the file  

foreach my $line (@syslogarray) 
{
foreach my $keyword (@keywordsarray)
{
    if ($line =~ m/\Q$keyword\E/)
    {
        if ((my $date) = $line =~  m/[A-z]+\s{2}\d{1,}\s((\d{2}[:]){2}\d{2})/)
        {   
            print "**". $keyword. "**". $date. "\n";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Matt, that doesn't work either I tried it earlier. I'm using Kali Linux if that makes any difference.

Comment: I just tested on [IDEONE and your regex works](http://ideone.com/wduhGO).

Comment: stribizhev What I want to achieve is the date and time, not just the date.

Comment: [Like that](http://ideone.com/9QlJ23)?

Comment: Yes like that, thank you.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this resolved my issue though? I'm not sure I understand your solution, perhaps you could explain?

Comment: I voted to close this question as to you're _Unclear_ as to what you're asking. If you care to update your post with what exactly you are trying to capture, I will change the close part. But, waiting for someone to make guesses, then selecting one of those guesses is not usually good form on SO.

Comment: `m/( [A-z]+ \s{2} \d{1,} \s (?: \d{2} [:] ){2} \d{2} )/x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use the capturing group around the whole pattern.

```
if ((my $date) = $line =~  m/([A-Z]+\s{2}\d+\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2})/i)
                             ^                                  ^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9QlJ23)

When you use `(my $date)` you tell the engine to put the contents matched by the first capturing group to the `$date` variable. So, all you need is to use a pair of unescaped parentheses around that part of pattern that will match the necessary string of text in the input string.

Note that `[A-z]` is ambiguous (see [[A-z] and [a-zA-Z] difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z)) and is better re-written as `[A-Za-z]` or `[A-Z]` with an `/i` modifier (as I suggested above).

Also, `\d{1,}` is equal to `\d+` (`+` quantifier means *1 or more occurrences*, same as `{1,0}`). You can use this latter variant since it is concise and more readable.

There is no point in placing `:` into a character class `[:]`, a colon does not have to be escaped in a regex pattern (unless it is a regex delimiter, and here it is not).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since now you have the privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a group around the date -

`/(?i)([a-z]+\s{2}\d{1,})\s((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2})/`

Formatted:

```
 (?i)
 ( [a-z]+ \s{2} \d{1,} )       # (1), Date
 \s 
 (                             # (2 start), Time
      (?: \d{2} : ){2}
      \d{2} 
 )                             # (2 end)
```

And, add another variable to the list.

`if (($date, $time) = $line =~  /([A-z]+\s{2}\d{1,})\s((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2})/)`

Comment: Can't you just put a group around the whole regex? It doesn't look like the OP is interested in separating the date from the time

Comment: This does in fact work, however I would like to store the date and time as one.

Comment: I guess I'm just without words.