# Match this regex on perl

Tags: regex, perl, matching

I am fairly new with Perl, and even more so with regex.
Have been trying to match the following, but without success:

- First, 3 to 4 letters (ideally case insensitive)
- Optionally a space (but not mandatory)
- Then, also optionally a known big-case letter (`M`) and a number out of `1,2,3`

An example of a valid string would be `abc`, but also `DEFG M2`. Invalid would be `mem M`, for example

What I have so far is:

```
$myExpr ~= m/^[a-z,A-z]{3,4}M[1,2,3]$/i
```

Not sure how to make the `M` and numbers optional

Comment: Note that `[A-z]` matches [more than you might expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try the following regular expression for it:

```
$myExpr =~ m/^([a-zA-Z]{3,4})(\s|)(M|)([1-3]|)$/;
```

- `([a-zA-Z]{3,4})` - Group of any character in this class: [a-zA-Z] with 3 to 4 repetition.
- `(\s|)` - Either there will be a **white-space**(space) **or not**.
- `(M|)` - Either there will be a Uppercase **M or not**.
- `([1-3]|)` - Either there will any charter this class: **`[1-3]` or not**.

**(OR) Try the following**

*I personally recommend this*

```
$myExpr =~ m/^([a-zA-Z]{3,4})(\s{0,1})(M{0,1})([1-3]{0,1})$/;
```

- `([a-zA-Z]{3,4})` - Group of any character in this class: `[a-zA-Z]` with 3 to 4 repetition i.e., it should contain minimum of 3 characters and maximum of 4.
- `(\s{0,1})` - Group of `\s` with 0 to 1 repetition i.e., it's optional.
- `(M{0,1})` - Group of character **`M`** with 0 to 1 repetition i.e., it's optional.
- `([1-3]{0,1})` - Group of any digit **`from 1 to 3`** with 0 to 1 repetition i.e., it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

Group your optional symbols with `(?:)` and use "zero or one" quantifier `?`.

```
$myExpr =~ m/^[a-zA-Z]{3,4}(?: M[123])?$/
```

I've also fixed errors in your regexp: you don't use `,` in character classes - that'd literraly mean "match ,", fixed `A-Z` range and removed `/i` modifier, since you didn't say if you need lower case M and first range already covers both small and big letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex. You don't need to use comma inside character class `[]`. And also remove `i` as you need to match with `M`.

```
$myExpr ~= m/^[a-zA-z]{3,4}(?: M[123])?$/
```

If you think your space is optional, then again add a `?` after that space too (i.e. `(?: ?M[123])`).