# Finding similar words (plurals and singulars) using grep in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a character variable with many words. 
For example...

```
    words   
1   funnel  
2   funnels
3   sprout
4   sprouts
5   sprouts.
6   chicken
7   chicken)
8   chicken(2)
```

Many of the words are the same, just with an `s` on the end or symbol (`)`, `.`) as a type

I want to find words that are plurals/singulars of each other, so I can remove the `s` from the end and remain with only singular values.

I also want to remove all the symbols from the end which are typos. For example,
* remove `chicken)`  because it is not a balanced parathesis
* but preserve `chicken(2)`

my current attempt has been

```
# Find words that end in `s`
grep("s$", df$words, ignore.case = TRUE, value = T)
# Remove the `s` from the end of words
df$words <- gsub("s$", "", df$words, ignore.case = T)
# Remove any typos with symbols at the the end of a word
gsub("[^A-z|0-9]|$", "", df$words)
```

My final code also includes words such as `chicken(2)`, which I do not wish to edit.

1. This shows me many plural words (words that end in `s`), however I have no idea if there is a singular version (the same word without the `s`).
2. How can I find words that end in grammar symbols / punctuations marks typos and remove those? (i.e. `(`, `.`, `!`). i.e remove unbalanced parentheses such as `chicken)`, but not `chicken(2)`

For example...

```
    words   
1   funnel  
2   funnel
3   sprout
4   sprout
5   sprout
6   chicken
7   chicken
8   chicken(2)
```

Comment: Well, you really made a typo. `df$words`, not `df$wprds`. Look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/4cw8Gd). However, that really does not check if there are 2 words that only differ in final `s`.

Comment: this is an example dataset, the issue was that gsub is case sensitive, but i've fixed that. 

I now need to remove the symbols on the end of the words

Comment: `gsub("[^A-z]$","",df$words)` should remove a single non letter from the end

Comment: I want to keep digits (0-9), but not symbols.

Comment: @R.Schifini: [\[A-z\] and \[a-zA-Z\] difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z). To remove all non-letters and non-digits, use `[^[:alnum:]]+$`. Try `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]+$", "", df$words)`

Comment: `grep("[^A-z|0-9]$",tmp$EVTYPE, value = T)` I thought I found a solution using, however it includes words such as `cat(2)` which are fine. 
I only want to remove typos, such as `cat)`. How can I preserve words which end in a pair of brackets with a digit inside  for example .
remove `cat)`  
preserve `cat(2)`

Comment: Do you mean you only want to keep words that can have (not necessarily) balanced parentheses? And you actually wanted to use `[^A-Za-z0-9]$`.

Comment: yes, I want to find words that do not have balanced parentheses, as well as words that end in fullstops or slashes.

Comment: :) That is a nightmare. See this demo: [`df$words <- gsub("(?s)^(?![^()]*+(\\((?>[^()]|(?1))*+\\)[^()]*+)++)(.*?)[^[:alnum:]]*$", "\\2", df$words, perl=T)`](https://ideone.com/XpZYq4)

Comment: After `++` there must be a `$`. Updated the above demo.

Answer (score 2):

The `str_replace_all` function from the `stringr` package will successively apply patterns and replacements to a vector of strings.  You might try

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(words, c("[^[:alnum:]]$" = "",  "s$" = "", "(\\(\\d*)" = "\\1\\)" ))
```