# Regex to match before and after a character

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am currently looking to use regex for a find/replace operation within my text editor, SublimeText 3.

What I have are a lot of lines that look like this:

```
array(self::var1, self::var2, class::var_1, class::var_2, self::varCaps)
```

what I would like to do is match each item in the array. The only thing I know for sure is that each one has the `::` characters in the middle.

I can match the string before the `::` characters pretty easily using

```
(?<=::)[a-zA-z0-9\_\-]+
//should match 'self::' in self::var1
```

I can also match after the `::` characters using

```
[a-zA-z0-9\_\-]+(?=::)
//should match 'var1' in self::var1
```

How would I combine these two things to create an expression which matches the entire thing?

EDIT: My text editor is SublimeText 3

Comment: Can't you use the comma delimiter? Seems simpler.

Comment: What is your text editor? Vim? The regex flavor differs between editors.

Comment: 1) I could use the comma delimiter for this case, however I am ultimately wanting to set up a little custom command for SublimeText that will quickly match any `string::string2` using regex. 2) I am using SublimeText 3 as my editor.

Comment: What about just `\w+::\w+`?

Comment: Steven, you are a genious... or I am just dense :P Not sure why I didn't think of that. Somehow I got it in my head that I needed to match the `::` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in your patterns: `[A-z]` range matches more than just lower- and uppercase letters (see [[A-z] and [a-zA-Z] difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z)).

To combine `(?<=::)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?=::)` (note the escapes with `_` and `-` are redundant) you can use `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+::[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` (note the `::` are part of the match which cannot be avoided as regex cannot match discontinuous text in 1 match operation).

Now, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is NOT the same as `\w` in Sublime Text as `\w` also matches all Unicode letters and digits! If you do not mind that, you can use `\w+::\w+`.

Also,if you want `-` to only appear once in between word characters, use `\w+(?:-\w+)*::\w+(?:-\w+)*` Unicode aware) or you may use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9_])*::[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9_])*` to match only ASCII letters/digits.

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation! Somehow I had it in my head that I had to match the `::` before everything else which is obviously not correct.