# jQuery - Modifying second part of the URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm making a `SPA` in `Laravel` and `jQuery`. The URL string is `domain.com/company/page`. As `company` is obligatory and variable, i wonder how i can edit `/page` part only? I make use of `window.PushState` to modify the URL without reloading.

My first guess would involve `RegEx`, i'm however not too familiar with `RegEx`, which makes this task kind of tricky. The hard part, is editing the second part of the URL only, as `company` can vary.

Cheers :)

Comment: What is it you wish to do ? Search for `/company/page` part and replace it with some other string ?

Comment: I want to replace the "page" part, with the given page from the referer, whilst keeping the company parameter :) 

Eg. /home, /stuff, /otherstuff

Comment: *I'm however not too familiar with RegExp.* Why not read up on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only wish to search and replace the `/page` then following is the simplest regex to do so:

`/\/[A-Za-z]+$/` 
It searches for `/` followed by any number of alphabets ranging from `A-Za-z` which appears at the end of the string( your URL ).

Simplest [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/6339wLd1/2/). 
If you wish to enumerate the search and replace for multiple links use loop and array or object. Something like [this.](https://jsfiddle.net/6339wLd1/3/)

Comment: You seem to like `[A-z]`, you are using it in your answers. But do you know what it can match? *alphabets ranging from `A-Za-z`* is not correct. See [\[A-z\] and \[a-zA-Z\] difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanx for pointing that out. Am a complete noob !