# How to Extract a substring that matches a Perticular Regular expression match from a String in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to write a function so that i can get all the substrings from a  string that matches a regular expression  , example : -

```
str <- "hello Brother How are you"
```

I want to extract all the substrings from `str` , where those substrings matches this regular expression - "[A-z]+ [A-z]+"

which results in -

```
"hello Brother"
"Brother How"
"How are"
"are you"
```

is there any library function which can do that ?

Comment: It could also be done like this: `library(zoo); rollapply(strsplit(str, " ")[[1]], 2, paste, collapse = " ")`

Comment: It worked fine and produced exactly what i wanted!!!
Thank you very much @Grothendieck  !!! 
You made my day !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with stringr library `str_match_all` function and the method Tim Pietzcker described in his answer (capturing inside an unanchored positive lookahead):

```
> library(stringr)
> str <- "hello Brother How are you"
> res <- str_match_all(str, "(?=\\b([[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+))")
> l <- unlist(res)
> l[l != ""]
## [1] "hello Brother" "Brother How"   "How are"       "are you"
```

Or to only get unqiue values:

```
> unique(l[l != ""])
##[1] "hello Brother" "Brother How"   "How are"       "are you"
```

I just advise to use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of [`[A-z]` since this pattern matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).

Comment: thanks @wiktor .. It worked !! ..  I was looking for this kind of function ... so thanks

Comment: You can actually access those strings without getting unique values, but you will still get empty values in the first column after running `str_match_all` (I tried to show a way how to get non-empty values). Note that `str_extract_all` only gets matches, thus, you cannot use that one.

Comment: ya @wiktor i wanted to to know the method of extracting the matches , and i have modified your code according to my need.. thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Regex matches "consume" the text they match, therefore (generally) the same bit of text can't match twice. But there are constructs called [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which don't consume the text they match, and which may contain [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

That makes your endeavor possible (although you can't use `[A-z]`, that doesn't do what you think it does):

```
(?=\b([A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+))
```

will match as expected; you need to look at group 1 of the match result, not the matched text itself (which will always be empty).

The `\b` [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is necessary to ensure that our matches always start at the beginning of a word (otherwise you'd also have the results `"ello Brother"`, `"llo Brother"`, `"lo Brother"`, and `"o Brother"`).

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yZ4mO8/1).

Comment: Thanks @tim , actually i am able to extract the first match , but i want to extract each and every possible matches ..