# How to define regex (including $) in Vugen

Tags: regex, loadrunner, vugen

when I am writing the following code, it is failed at runtime
But without end string char '$' at the end of the regex, the script is being passed.

```
lr_xml_find("XML={response}",
        "Query=/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/p4:TechParm/p3:SessionID",
         "UseRegExp=yes",
     "Value=^[A-z0-9]{8}[-][A-z0-9]{8}[-][A-z0-9]{8}[-][A-z0-9]{8}$",
      LAST);
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Comment: I'm not sure you know what `[A-z]` means...

Comment: Also, without the value being tested, we can't help you a lot...

Comment: This is the sample test value 26040600-00000608-00155654-989ED000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z

Comment: Try with the following regex : `^[A-Z\d]{8}(?:-[A-Z\d]{8}){3}$`