# What is the regular expression for all non-alphabetic characters in php?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse a file and analyze it. To do this, I've used preg_split() to break the document into an array. I only want words in the array (otherwise alpha characters). The regular expression I used is:

```
$noAlpha = "/[\s]+|[^A-z]+|\W|\r/";
```

However, I'm getting instances of blanks in the array. I believe it has to do with a line with a return only (`\r`) and nothing else on it.

I'm only using .txt files. What would I need to add to the regex to account for this?

Comment: You may just extract the words with `preg_match_all('~\p{L}+~', $text, $words)`

Comment: `[^A-z]` likely doesn't match what you expect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z

Comment: Thank you for the comments, they helped me become aware of some details I didn't consider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract all the words (only letters), you can use this

```
preg_match_all('/[^\W\d_]+/',$string,$matches)
```

If you want digits as well, then the pattern should be `'/[^\W_]+/'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
   `$noAlpha = "/\s+|[^a-zA-Z]+|\W|\r/";`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$noAlpha = "/\s*\W\s*/";
```

However, I also would extract the words with `preg_match_all` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using preg_match_all