# Validate name using Python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to return true if name is valid. Name can contain:

1. upper or lower case characters
2. no numbers or special characters
3. can be one or two words with a single space in the middle
4. first name and last name can be between 2-25 characters each

eg.

- `John Smith` = true
- `John` = true
- `JoHn` = true
- `John Sm1th` = false
- `John $mith` = false
- `J0hn` = false
- `John  Smith` = false (two spaces between names)

Here is my code thus far. It fails some of these test cases.

```
import re

if re.findall('[A-Za-z]{2,25}\s[A-Za-z]{2,25}', string):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Comment: First, to test a string don't use `re.findall` but `re.match`.

Comment: Don't make us try to guess which test cases fail.  It should be part of your question!

Comment: @DanFarrell Pass/Fail for each test case was provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match one or two words, you need to make either the first name or the last name optional, also you need anchors to assure it's not partial matching or use `re.fullmatch` instead of `re.findall`:

```
lst = ['John Smith', 'John', 'JoHn', 'John Sm1th', 'John $mith', 'J0hn', 'John  Smith']

import re
[re.fullmatch('[A-Za-z]{2,25}( [A-Za-z]{2,25})?', x) for x in lst]
# [<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='John Smith'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='John'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='JoHn'>, None, None, None, None]
```

Convert result to bool:

```
[bool(re.fullmatch('[A-Za-z]{2,25}( [A-Za-z]{2,25})?', x)) for x in lst]
# [True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Where `[A-Za-z]` can be shortened as  `[A-z]`

Comment: @albert: no it's wrong, look at the ascii table to see all characters between A and z. However, you can use `[a-z]` with the `re.I` flag.

Comment: @albert You actually can't, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).

Comment: is there any practical difference between a regex of " " and "\s"?

Comment: @WoodyPride `\s` can match normal white space, tab `\t` and new line characters `\n` or `\r` on windows while `" "` only matches normal white space.

Answer (score 0):

`'[A-Za-z]{2,25}||\s[A-Za-z]{2,25}'` this should work. You can test your regular expressions at 
https://pythex.org/