# Regex in go lang matching period and - and A-z 0-9

Tags: regex, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to do a Regex in Go to match s3 bucket urls.

so far i have

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "http://s3.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3-eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "//s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
        "https://(.+?).s3.amazonaws.com",
        "//s3.amazonaws.com/([A-z0-9-]+)",
        "//s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/(.+?)/",
```

but this is overkill so i was looking at

`//s3.amazonaws.com/([A-z0-9-]+)`

but this misses out the . but when i do //s3.amazonaws.com/([A-z0-9-]\.+) it does not match any of the strings found.

I am currently trying to match it against

`//s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.name/` and `//s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name-here`

any suggestions?

Comment: `.` is a metacharacter in regexes, you have to escape it with `\ `

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: You can use `//s3.amazonaws.com/([-A-z0-9.]+) `

Answer (score 3):

In your regex you use `[A-z0-9-]`. Note that `[A-z]` [is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z) from `[A-Za-z]`.

To match a literal dot you could escape it: `\.`

This part `([A-z0-9-]\.+)` in this regex `//s3.amazonaws.com/([A-z0-9-]\.+)` will match your character class once and then one or more times the dot like `j.....`

To fully match the 2 urls from your example, you could add a dot in the character class, add an optional forward slash at the end and you might omit the capturing group (parenthesis around the character class`([])`) if you only want to match the full url and not use the data in the captured group itself for further usage.

[`//s3\.amazonaws\.com/[.A-z0-9-]+/?`](https://regex101.com/r/DaqwLV/2)

Looking at the other urls in your example, maybe this regex can help you and you can adapt it to your further requirements:

[`(?:https?:)?//[A-z0-9.-]+\.amazonaws\.com(?:/(?:[A-z0-9.-]*/?))?`](https://regex101.com/r/DaqwLV/4)

Answer (score 0):

Add dot to the character class:

```
//s3.amazonaws.com/([-A-z0-9.]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DkLgBB/1/)