# Regex to extract name from a string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regular expression to extract the name from a string.  The name always follow by a protocol.  The protocols are:  `ssh` , `folder`, `http`.

```
Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o r John ssh 0 *
Thu May 23 22:42:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o i Jake folder 0 *
Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o t Steve http 0 *
```

The expected output would be:

```
John
Jake
Steve
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following PCRE regex (as you haven't precised which language):

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s+(?:ssh|folder|http))
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/t62Ra7/4/

**Explanations:**

- `\b` start the match from a word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z]+` match any sequence of ASCII character in a-zA-Z range, you might have to generalise this to accept Unicode letters.
- `(?=` lookahead pattern to add the constraint that the name is followed by one of the protocols
- `\s+` a whitespace class char
- `(?:ssh|folder|http)` non-capturing group for the protocols `ssh`, `folder` or `http`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+(?=\s(?=ssh|folder|http))
```

Regex Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ygRuqR/2).

```js
let regex = /\b[A-Za-z]+(?=\s(?=ssh|folder|http))/g;

[match] = "Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o r John ssh 0 *".match(regex);
console.log(match); //John

[match] = "Thu May 23 22:42:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o i Jake folder 0 *".match(regex);
console.log(match); //Jake

[match] = "Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o t Steve http 0 *".match(regex);
console.log(match); //Steve
```

Regex explanation:

> `\b` defines a word boundary to start match
>
> `[A-Za-z]` match any alphabet, any case
>
> `+` repeat previous character any number of times till next pattern
>
> `(?=` finds lookahead pattern (which won't be included in matching group)
>
> `\s` a whitespace
>
> `(?=ssh|folder|http)` another lookahead to either `ssh`, `folder` or `http`

Putting it all together, the regex looks for a word that is followed by a space and then one of the following: ssh, folder, or http.

Comment: 2 points here: you do not need to have nested lookahead, and the more important point is `[A-z]` does not behave how you think it does!!!!! this will not match only letters!!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z

Comment: your regex does accept `J]ohn`, `Ja[ke`, ... >>> https://regex101.com/r/T4gayx/1/

Comment: Good catch, much appreciated! Fixed now.

Comment: `[A-ZA-z]` will still match more than what you want https://regex101.com/r/T4gayx/2/, the correct range is `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Fixed the typo in the text. The code snippet and demo code was fine though. Again, thanks for the catch!

Comment: Visually >>> https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html
`[A-z]` will accept char for which Dec ascii value is included between `65` and `122`, including `[\^_` that are not letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might do it in Java.

```java
String[] str = {
            "Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o r John ssh 0 *    ",
            "Thu May 23 22:42:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o i Jake folder 0 * ",
            "Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o t Steve http 0 *  ",
      };

      String pat = "(\\w+) (ssh|folder|http)"; // need to escape the second \
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat);
      for (String s : str) {
         Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
         if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
         }

      }
   }
```

The actual pattern is in the string pat and can be used with other regex engines.  This simply matches a name followed by a space followed by the protocols or'd together.  But it captures the name in the first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to take the single letter and space present right before the names as a left boundary, then collect the names' letters and save it in capturing group `$1`, maybe similar to:

```
\s+[a-z]\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

We can also add more boundaries to it, if it might be necessary.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CFZ9u3/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/CFZ9u3/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /\s+[a-z]\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)/gm;
const str = `Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o r John ssh 0 *
Thu May 23 22:42:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o i Jake folder 0 *
Thu May 23 22:41:55 2019 19 10.10.10.20 22131676 /mnt/tmp/test.txt b s o t Steve http 0 *`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```