# RegEx for capturing values in nested brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I was trying to use a regular expression to match the inner text between two characters, but I am getting the wrong text

I tried putting [A-z]* instead of .* for matching only the inner text and it worked. But I need to match non-letter characters too.

```regex
/\[?(,? ?\[(\[(.+)-(.+)\])\])\]?/g
```

This is my regular expression and i want to match the characters between the square brackets:

> [[[**hello-hello]],[[hi**-hi]]]

The bold characters are the one matched.

> I'd expect to match [[[**hello-hello**]],[[hi-hi]]] in match 1 and
>   [[[hello-hello]],[[**hi-hi**]]] in match two.

Comment: Set the capture to non-greedy (.+?) Or use ([^\\]]+)

Comment: Also be aware that `[A-z]` will [consume square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).

Comment: Can you add example input and output?

Comment: @DenisGiffeler yes, it works! I can either set the U flag or the ?. Put your comment as an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything in between the `[]` would be desired, then we might simplify our expression to maybe:

```
(?:\[+)(.+?)(?:\]+)
```

Here, we capture our likely desired substring in this capturing group:

```
(.+?)
```

Then, we add two boundaries on its left and right sides using two non-capturing groups:

```
(?:\[+)
(?:\]+)
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /(?:\[+)(.+?)(?:\]+)/g;
const str = `[[[hello-hello]]
[[hi-hi]]]
[[hi hi]]]`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JkhOlF/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like this:

```
\[(?!\[)([^\]]*)\]
```

This will match a `[` character, if not followed by a `[` character. It will then match any amount of non `]` characters capturing them in group 1. Followed by matching a `]` character.

```js
const text = "[[[hello-hello]],[[hi-hi]]]";
const regex = /\[(?!\[)([^\]]*)\]/g;
var match;

while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

Alternatively you can leave out the capturing group and drop the first and last character of every match.

```js
const text = "[[[hello-hello]],[[hi-hi]]]";
const regex = /\[(?!\[)[^\]]*\]/g;

console.log(
  text.match(regex)
      .map(match => match.slice(1, -1))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex I came up with:

```
\[+([a-z- A-Z]+)\]+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IAlM5N/3)

Comment: I need to capture characters like spaces too. That captures only letters

Comment: I meant I had to capture every character between the brackets... Sorry if I wasn't too clear

Answer (score 1):

You could use 1 capturing group to capture your values.

The values before and after the hyphen could be matches using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `\[([^][\n-]+` matching not an opening or closing bracket, a hyphen or a newline.

In your pattern you use a dot which will match any character except a newline so the negated character class contains a newline to prevent crossing lines.

```
\[([^\][\n-]+-[^\][\n-]+)]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `[^\][\n-]+` Negated character class, match 1+ times not `]`, `[`, `-` or a newline
  - `-` Match `-`
  - `[^\][\n-]+` Match 1+ times not `]`, `[`, `-` or a newline
- `)` Close capturing group
- `]` Match `]` char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZRyvlP/1)

```js
const regex = /\[([^\][\n-]+-[^\][\n-]+)]/g;
const str = `[[[hello-hello]],[[hi-hi]]]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx

```
(?<=\[)([a-z- A-Z]+)(?=\])
```

---

`(?<=\\[)`: Start with a bracket, but does not contain a bracket.

`(?=\\])`: End with a bracket, but does not contain a bracket.

Detailed explanations can be found in this [link](https://regex101.com/r/EZY17G/1).