# Find Regular Expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, nsregularexpression

I have created a regular expression to find a certain pattern(example{ `008-150A-003E`,`9C1-E10-010` etc...) from a a paragraph but its failing by fetching me values based on length of the pattern.
this is the Regx I wrote:

```
[A-z0-9]{3,4}[\S][A-z0-9]{3,4}[\S][A-z0-9]{3,4}
```

For testing I have used this paragraph given below:

```
****Test Paragraph******


PCB ASSLY (9C1-E10-010)
PLEASE ARRANGE QUOTATION FOR THE ABOVE ITEAM AT THE EARLIEST 9C1 E10.010

008-150A-003E  
Form BHUVANESWARI COTSPIN INDIA P LTD
asdfghjklpo
***************
```

I want to find only the patterns 9C1-E10-010, 008-150A-003E  etc... from the above test paragraph.
PS: the expression can be of theis form also i.e;9C1 E10.010, I'm inlcuding that in test Paragraph also

Comment: The point is that you are using `\S`, any non-whitespace, to match hyphens. Use `-` or `[^\w\s]` (to match any punctuation) instead. Also, replace `A-z` with `A-Za-z` as `[A-z]` matches more than just letters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using \S because my pattern can come with hyphens,\. or even white spaces example  9C1-E10-010 can come as 9C1 E10.010 also . I'M sorry for not mentioning that earlier

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. It must be working for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you are using `\S`, any non-whitespace, to match hyphens. Use `-` or `[^\w\s]` (to match any punctuation), or plain `\W` (to match any non-word char) instead. Also, replace `A-z` with `A-Za-z` as [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z). Also, to enforce length restriction on start/end, you need (at least) word boundaries.

Use

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4}\W[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4}\W[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PbKx9D/2)