# Regex Help for User ID

Tags: regex

Fairly new to regex, looking to identify a user id pattern that is all alpha, is exactly 6 characters, and the second character is always a Z.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Give us an example what you expect from a text as output

Comment: [a-zA-Z]{1}\Z[a-zA-Z]{4} maybe

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
\w(Z|z)\w{4}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: that doesn't find a match, an example would be bzh7wv.  *Edit* It can include digits 1-9.

Comment: But you said the second char was always a "Z" (upper case!) Have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want something to detect something like this:

> jZabcd

What you could do is something like this:

`[A-Za-z][Z]([A-Za-z]{4})`

Breakdown:

[A-Za-z] = detects all alpha big and small letters only once.

[Z] = checks if there is only a big "Z".

() = a group to make it easier.

{4} = checks if there is 4 times from what was infront of the 4.

[A-Za-z]{4} = checks if there are 4 letters from big A-Z and small a-z.

I hope this helps you out and please expand your question next time a little more.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z for what `A-z` actually matches!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann thank you kind sir!
Damn now I need to change all my codes from earlier projects...better now than later.

Comment: Well, it's never too late too improve ...