# Parse string starting with pattern starting with digit and ending white space BEFORE next digit

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python 3.8

I have a string that looks like this:

> '1-New Bathroom 2-New Kitchen 3-New Garden 4-Caribbean Holiday'

I want to parse it into a list of tuples like this:

```
[(1, 'New Bathroom'),
 (2, 'New Kitchen'),
 (3, 'New Garden'),
 (4, 'Caribbean Holiday')
]
```

This is what I have managed to come up with so far, but it looks ugly - is there a more succinct way of matching.

```
"^([0-9]{1,2}){1}\-[aA-zZ\s+]+"
```

it would be useful if you could explain the improved matching logic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `^([0-9]{1,2}){1}\-[aA-zZ\s+]+` starts with an anchor `^` which limits the matching to the start of the string.

You can omit `{1}` and the ranges in the character class are not the same as `[a-zA-Z]` as `A-z` [matches more characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z).

Adding `\s` in the single character class can possible also match only spaces or newlines, so `4-`  would also match.

---

You can use a pattern with 2 capture groups, and use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to return the capture group values in tuples, and end the match with a-zA-Z chars to not match spaces only.

```
\b([0-9]{1,2})-([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `([0-9]{1,2})` Capture **group 1**, match 1-2 digits
- `-` Match a hyphen
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ chars a-zA-Z
  - `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)+` Optionally repeat 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `)*` Close group 2
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pKe9jL/1)

For example

```
import re

s = '1-New Bathroom 2-New Kitchen 3-New Garden 4-Caribbean Holiday'
pattern = r'\b([0-9]{1,2})-([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\b'
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('1', 'New Bathroom'), ('2', 'New Kitchen'), ('3', 'New Garden'), ('4', 'Caribbean Holiday')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
matches = re.findall(r"(\d+)-(.*?)(?= \d|$)", s)
results = [(int(n), m) for n, m in matches]
```

- `(\d+)` matches a sequence of digits.
- `(.*?)` matches a sequence of arbirary characters in a non-greedy manner.
- Finally, positive lookahead `(?= \d|$)` checks if what follows is either a space and a digit or the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` with a list comprehension:

```
import re
s = '1-New Bathroom 2-New Kitchen 3-New Garden 4-Caribbean Holiday'
r = [(int((k:=i.split('-'))[0]), k[1]) for i in re.findall('\d+\-\w+\s\w+', s)]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'New Bathroom'), (2, 'New Kitchen'), (3, 'New Garden'), (4, 'Caribbean Holiday')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

txt = '1-New Bathroom 2-New Kitchen 3-New Garden 4-Caribbean Holiday'
m = re.findall(r'(\d+)-([A-Za-z ]+)', txt) # the pattern contains two capture groups (number)(text)
out = [(int(v[0]), v[1].strip()) for v in m] # handle the capture groups (number,text) and make the list of tuples
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 'New Bathroom'), (2, 'New Kitchen'), (3, 'New Garden'), (4, 'Caribbean Holiday')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use two expressions, one to find an item, one to separate it:

```
import re
 
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+-.+?(?=\s+\d-|$)')
item_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)-(.+)')
 
text = "1-New Bathroom 2-New Kitchen 3-New Garden 4-Caribbean Holiday"
 
result = [item.groups()
          for chunk in pattern.findall(text)
          for item in [item_pattern.search(chunk)]]
 
print(result)
```

This yields

```
[('1', 'New Bathroom'), ('2', 'New Kitchen'), ('3', 'New Garden'), ('4', 'Caribbean Holiday')]
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/EL3Og6).