# Filter all rows that start with any Latin alphabetic letter in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

How can I filter all rows that start with any Latin alphabetic letter in R

sample code that is not working

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame( marks = c(20.1, 30.2, 40.3, 50.4, 60.5),
                  
                  age = c(21:25),
                  
                  roles = c('Software Eng.', 'Software Dev', 
                            'Data Analyst', 'Data Eng.',
                            '5Sigma'))

df %>% filter(grep("[A-z]", roles))
```

Desired output

```
  marks age         roles
1  20.1  21 Software Eng.
2  30.2  22  Software Dev
3  40.3  23  Data Analyst
4  50.4  24     Data Eng.
```

Comment: The `field:` is not a substring in your data.  Also, `filter` expects a logical vector whereas `grep` return index. `df %>% filter(grepl("^[A-z]+", roles))`?

Comment: Thanks, this also solved my problem, Regex is my biggest weakness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `[A-z]` is not the same as `[A-Za-z]`, you need to be more careful with character classes. (See [Difference between regex [A-z] and [a-zA-Z]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4923380/3358272) and ignore the [java](/questions/tagged/java) portions.)

Second, where does `field:` come in? Do this:

```r
df %>%
  filter(grepl("^[A-Za-z]", roles))
#   marks age         roles
# 1  20.1  21 Software Eng.
# 2  30.2  22  Software Dev
# 3  40.3  23  Data Analyst
# 4  50.4  24     Data Eng.
```

(Plus the previous comment about `grepl` versus `grep`.)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, and will dive into those resources. Regex is my biggest weakness