# Remove parts from a string using a regular expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regexp-replace

I have a list of strings like so:

```
['NN.KTXS/KTXE.FOO BAR.STACK.OVERFLOW', 'NN.WFXL.Harlan KY.Harlan.KY', 'NN.WRGB/WCWN.Los Angeles CA.Burbank.CA', 'NN.KVII/KVIH.Denver.Denver.CO', 'NN.KEYE.Denver.Denver.CO']
```

I am trying to use a regular expression to strip out the portion of text between `NN.` (including that) and the second `.`, so the list would look like:

```
['FOO BAR.STACK.OVERFLOW', 'Harlan KY.Harlan.KY', 'Los Angeles CA.Burbank.CA', 'Denver.Denver.CO', 'Denver.Denver.CO']
```

I have tried using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SfrrLK/1) to build and test this, using: `"NN\.[A-z]{?}\."` but I am not getting any matches.

How can I build that regular expression?

Comment: You can use this pattern `NN\..*?\.`

Comment: Why a regex? `[s.split('.', 2)[-1] for s in lst]` seems straightforward to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern `[A-z]{?}` matches a range A-z *(which is [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z) as `[A-Za-z]`)* then an optional `{` and `}`

To match from `NN.` to the next dot, you can use a negated character class `[^.]*` matching any character except a dot:

```
NN\.[^.]*\.
```

Replace with an empty string.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H3nuGG/1).

```
import re

lst = ['NN.KTXS/KTXE.FOO BAR.STACK.OVERFLOW', 'NN.WFXL.Harlan KY.Harlan.KY', 'NN.WRGB/WCWN.Los Angeles CA.Burbank.CA', 'NN.KVII/KVIH.Denver.Denver.CO', 'NN.KEYE.Denver.Denver.CO']
print([re.sub(r"NN\.[^.]*\.", "", s) for s in lst])
```

Output

```
['FOO BAR.STACK.OVERFLOW', 'Harlan KY.Harlan.KY', 'Los Angeles CA.Burbank.CA', 'Denver.Denver.CO', 'Denver.Denver.CO']
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.

Start by replacing `{?}` with `+`.

`{?` means to match `{` 0 or 1 times.  Then `}` is being literally matched.

That will match `NN.WFXL` out of `'NN.WFXL.Harlan KY.Harlan.KY'` and `NN.KEYE` out of `'NN.KEYE.Denver.Denver.CO'`

To match the same portion of the others, expand your character set to include a `/`

`[A-z]` becomes `[A-z\/]`

and lastly, to be more deliberate...  `[A-z]` matches the following characters:

`` ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ``

Perhaps this was a deliberate choice, but if you want to match only letters, case insensitive, use `[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> x = ['NN.KTXS/KTXE.FOO BAR.STACK.OVERFLOW', 'NN.WFXL.Harlan KY.Harlan.KY', 'NN.WRGB/WCWN.Los Angeles CA.Burbank.CA', 'NN.KVII/KVIH.Denver.Denver.CO', 'NN.KEYE.Denver.Denver.CO']
>>> y = ['.'.join(val.split('.')[2:]) for val in x]
>>> y
['FOO BAR.STACK.OVERFLOW', 'Harlan KY.Harlan.KY', 'Los Angeles CA.Burbank.CA', 'Denver.Denver.CO', 'Denver.Denver.CO']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NN\.([\w\/]+)\.
```

To be adjusted to your needs.
Then you get the first and only group.

Answer (score 0):

All of these other answers seem too complicated for me so I would do something like this:

```
list = ['NN.KTXS/KTXE.FOO BAR.STACK.OVERFLOW', 'NN.WFXL.Harlan KY.Harlan.KY', 'NN.WRGB/WCWN.Los Angeles CA.Burbank.CA', 'NN.KVII/KVIH.Denver.Denver.CO', 'NN.KEYE.Denver.Denver.CO']

replacement []
for i, e in enumerate(list):
    elist = e.split(".")
    newvalue = ""
    for i2 in elist[2:len(elist)]: newvalue += i2
    replacement.append(newvalue)
list = replacement.copy()
```

I hope this works for you, but Im sure you've already sued the other guys' answers.