# How to determine which match belongs to which pattern?

Tags: python, regex

Given multiple patterns that need to be extracted from the text below.

```
import re

s = 'This text2 11contains 4 numbers and 6 words.'
```

For example assuming I need to extract words and numbers separately, I can do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s)
['This', 'text', 'contains', 'numbers', 'and', 'words']
```

and

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', s)
['2', '11', '4', '6']
```

However, if I want to combine both in a single expression, I would do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-z]+|\d+', s)
['This', 'text', '2', '11', 'contains', '4', 'numbers', 'and', '6', 'words']
```

But I need to tell which belongs to which pattern. In this case I can simply check if `isnumeric()` and group each accordingly but with the patterns getting any more complicated, there is no way of telling unless each pattern is extracted separately which will eventually become inefficient if a large number of documents and patterns need to be extracted separately. What would be a way of obtaining the match types? For the example above it would be something like:

```
['This', 'text', '2', '11', 'contains', '4', 'numbers', 'and', '6', 'words']
['word', 'word', 'number', ...]
```

or a simple enumeration of each group `[0, 0, 1, 1, ...]`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Perhaps you can enclose a branch in capturing group (e.g. `([a-zA-Z]+)|\d+`) then check if that group was matched (e.g. `if match[1]: ...`)?

Comment: Note that `A-z` is probably not what you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4923380).

Comment: @InSync failing shift key, I mean `A-Z`. Simply if i have `patterns = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, ...]` and some text, i need to extract all in a single expression and be able to tell which matches in the `findall` results belongs to which pattern.

Comment: So you think obtaining whether it matched a number or letter is magically handed out by `findfall()` ? Pretty ridiculous since the only thing you have to test is weather one group matched or not. You think all the answers below get you out of checking weather a group matched, or weather an element in an array is `word` or `number`, or even if an element has no length ? You haven't shown any relationship between the words or numbers. Come on get real !

Comment: Either `re.findall(r'[a-zA-z]+|\d+', s)` or `re.findall(r'[a-zA-z]+', s) re.findall(r'\d+', s)` or `re.findall(r'([a-zA-z]+)|(\d+)', s)`

Comment: If you use `re.findall(r'[a-zA-z]+|\d+', s)` you can sort the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use named group matching:

```
s = 'This text2 11contains 4 numbers and 6 words.'
matches_it =  re.finditer(r'(?P<word>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?P<number>\d+)', s)
res = [(m.group(), m.lastgroup) for m in matches_it]
```

---

```
[('This', 'word'), ('text', 'word'), ('2', 'number'), ('11', 'number'), ('contains', 'word'), ('4', 'number'), ('numbers', 'word'), ('and', 'word'), ('6', 'number'), ('words', 'word')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use groups, like [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-18). For example, with [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) and [`re.Match.groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict):

```
regex = r'(?P<word>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?P<number>\d+)'
matches = re.finditer(regex, s)
for m in matches:
    for k, v in m.groupdict().items():
        if v is not None:
            print(k, v)
```

```
word This
word text
number 2
number 11
word contains
number 4
word numbers
word and
number 6
word words
```

Answer (score 2):

Using groups, something like the follwoing will do:

```
>>> [(w, "word") if w else (n, "number") for w, n in re.findall(r'([a-zA-z]+)|(\d+)', s)]
[('This', 'word'),
 ('text', 'word'),
 ('2', 'number'),
 ('11', 'number'),
 ('contains', 'word'),
 ('4', 'number'),
 ('numbers', 'word'),
 ('and', 'word'),
 ('6', 'number'),
 ('words', 'word')]
```